# Click outside toggle menu and close menu

Tags: javascript, toggle

I have this menu for desktop and mobile and it works fine so far .., I just don't know how to close the menu again, when a user click on a link or outside the menu, not only on the button. Maybe someone could help me? Thank you!

This is the html

```
<div id="wrapper1" class="menuDisplayed">
    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <div id="sidebar-wrapper1">
      <ul class="sidebar-nav1">
        Texts
        <li><a href="sweater" rel="history" data-tags="link1">Link1</a></li>
        <li><a href="cardigan" rel="history" data-tags="link2">link2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    
    <!-- Page Content -->
        <div id="page-content-wrapper">
      <div class="">
        <div class="">
          <div class="">
            <a href="#" id="menu-toggle" class="icon-link">︎&nbsp;</a>
```

this is the css code

```
/* Sidebar */
#sidebar-wrapper1{
  z-index:1;
  position: absolute;
  padding-right: 0;
  margin-top:15rem;
  margin-right: -200px;
  width:0;
  right: 200px;
  height:60rem;
  overflow-y:hidden;
  background: white;
  opacity:0.8;
  transition:all .5s;
  display:flex;
  align-items:left;
}

#sidebar-wrapper1{
  Display:none;

/* Main Content */

#page-content-wrapper{
  width: 100%;  
  position: absolute;
  margin-top:12rem;
  padding:15px;
  transition:all .5s;
  right: 7px;
}

#menu-toggle{
transition:all .3s;
font-family:"Nitti", monospaced;
font-size:1.5rem;
float: right;

}
/* Change the width of the sidebar to display it*/

#wrapper1.menuDisplayed #sidebar-wrapper1{
  width:200px;
}

#wrapper1.menuDisplayed #page-content-wrapper{
  padding-right:200px;
}
```

and the script. It worked nice so far!

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#menu-toggle").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#wrapper1").toggleClass("menuDisplayed");
      });
});
```

Comment: Add an event listener for when you are doing a body click that removes the class `menuDisplayed`

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer!, I just don't how to write java script! I try to learn by trial and error :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
$(document).click((e) => {
    if (!$(e.traget).closest('#wrapper1, #menu-toggle').length) {
        $("#wrapper1").removeClass("menuDisplayed");
    }
});
```

What this does is to add a click event listener to the document and every time something is clicked, check if that clicked element is the menu itself or a descendent of the menu, if that is not the case, close the menu.

Comment: I See! Thanks again. It just doesn't work...

Comment: @anke I've edited my answer to add `.length` to the if condition. Did you use this version of the code and it still didn't work ?

Comment: oh thanks! No, now the menu did not open

Comment: @anke I've edited my answer again. Try this version.

Comment: It keeps quiet! (don't open)

Comment: I should look for an easier one to adapt to my needs... I just liked the short javascript :)